# The try and catch statement gives me no results?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

**The aim of the code is to read some data from a file. The data is split into a few lines and the data on each line is split using the "-" character. The code should spliut the data into separate strings and transfer the separate strings into an array called "splitLine". The point of the test data is that is throws an "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" in which it does. However, after this exception is given, the catch should simply allow the code to continue however it's not working. **

```
public class asd 

{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String line = "";
        String[] splitLine;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the file name: ");
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        Scanner fileReader = null;

        try
        {
            File Fileobject = new File (filename);
            fileReader = new Scanner (Fileobject);
            System.out.println("The file " + filename + " contains the following lines");
            System.out.println("==============================");
            int x=0;




            while(fileReader.hasNext())
            { 
                try 
                {
                    line = fileReader.nextLine();
                    splitLine = line.split(" - "); //For assignment use line.split(" - ")
                    System.out.printf("Title: %20s \nAuthor: %17s \nPublisher: %9s\nPrice: %10s\nPages: %8s\nISBN: %16s\n===================\n", splitLine[x] , splitLine[x+1], splitLine[x+2], splitLine[x+3], splitLine[x+4], splitLine[x+5]);
                } 
                catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  e) 
                {
                    continue;
                }





        }
    }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error - file does not exist");
                System.exit(0);
            } 

    }
}
```

Comment: How isn't it working? What happens next? (Here, I am guessing your catch exception runs more than expected. Put a print statement there.)

Comment: Please do not attempt to **bold** all the text in your question. It hurts our eyes.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to do validations on input before accessing it, and not just to use it and fail on exceptions.

---

**Another Direction:**

Anyway - per your message, your data is organized with " - ", so why not just to save the same data as JSON file ?

Then you can read it to your object like that:
First, create your own **Article.java** class
Then, write code like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.*

    public static void someMethod()
    {
        File file = new File("....somepath...\\Desktop\\data.json");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Article article = mapper.readValue(file , Article.class);

        System.out.printf("Title: %20s \nAuthor: %17s \nPublisher: %9s\nPrice: %10s\nPages: %8s\nISBN: %16s\n===================\n", article.getTitle(), article.getPublisher(), article.getPrice(), article.getPages(), article.getSomethingMore1(), article.getSomethingMore2());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I understand you want to skip iteration when the `splitLine` doesn't contain the required values?
In that case wouldn't it be simpler to just check if you have enough params?

```
 splitLine = line.split(" - "); //For assignment use line.split(" - ")
 if(splitLine.lenght != 6) {
  continue;
 }
 System.out.printf("Title: %20s \nAuthor: %17s \nPublisher: %9s\nPrice: %10s\nPages: %8s\nISBN: %16s\n===================\n", splitLine[x] , splitLine[x+1], splitLine[x+2], splitLine[x+3], splitLine[x+4], splitLine[x+5]);
```

Also I would recommend extracting the inner try to a separate method for better readability